# How can I add self-signed certs to the docker daemon on a Mac?

Tags: macos, docker, ssl, docker-for-mac

I realize this question is not going to age well based on the volatility of Docker (especially for OS X), but I'm willing to ask it.

I'm using Docker 17.12.0-ce-mac49 and I'm trying to add my corporate self-signed certs to the daemon.

The way I used to do this was:

```
screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/tty
cd /tmp
wget http://example.com/root.crt
cat root.crt >> /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
/etc/init.d/docker restart
```

But now I find that I'm unable to append the cert to the daemon's cert store because linuxkit is a read-only filesystem.

Surely there's some way to make the docker daemon respect my self-signed cert... but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try storing the certs on a mapped volume. That would allow you to easily update them, and the feature is probably not going away ever.